# Find the sum to n terms as well as the sum to infinity of the series:

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Find the sum to $n$ terms as well as the sum to infinity of the series:

$$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4\cdot 2!} + \frac{1}{5\cdot 3!} +\cdots.$$

I was trying this question many times but I didn't get the answer. I was using geometric series formula, but it was not applicable here...I don't know where I have to start, and I don't know any hint about this series....

If anybody helps me, I would be very thankful to him.

Comment: Hint:  this looks like the integral of $x^2e^x$ at $x=1$...or something close to that.

Answer (score 10):

Each term is
$$\frac1{(n+2)n!}.$$

Write this as
$$\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}
=\frac{(n+2)-1}{(n+2)!}
=\frac1{(n+1)!}-\frac1{(n+2)!}
$$
and the sum telescopes.